# Tomcat is running on port 80 but Connection Refused when trying to connect

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to get Tomcat to work on port 80 & 443 with an SSL certificate. When tomcat first starts I can connect on port 8080 and everything looks great.

After that I modified the two lines in server.xml file to look like below

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
        clientAuth="false" port="443" scheme="https" secure="true"
        sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1"
        keystoreFile="/opt/tomcat/certificates/CERTIFICATE.pfx"
        keystorePass="PASSWORD"
        keystoreType="PKCS12" />

<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="443"/>
```

After this I installed authbind and did the whole process with authbind and added authbind --deep to the tomcat start script.

Restart tomcat and it starts with no erros

querying netstat shows that 80 and 443 are listening

```
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      17181/java
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      17181/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN      17181/java
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      17181/java
```

when I try to curl localhost I get a connection refused error.

```
curl localhost
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

If I revert back to 8080 everything works fine. I have been scratching my head over this for hours. Please help me

Comment: Your tomcat has not started. Plz check `tomcat/logs`.

Comment: Anish, what makes you think that tomcat has not started? I can check the status of tomcat and it says that it is started and the PID is 17181 which is why I queried netstat for that port which shows that its listening on 80 and 443 and the shutdown port as well.

Comment: mind trying `curl -g -6 "http://[::1]:80/" `?

Comment: check your iptables/firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
etc/default/tomcat{VERSION} file -> set AUTHBIND=yes
```

then:

```
sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chmod 500 /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chown tomcat{VERSION} /etc/authbind/byport/80
```

restart tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Perform a check that your installation is correct and your configuration is correct.

Check your firewall, if it shouldn't be a problem, disable it.

Restart your server and check if it's available.

If it is still not available, post the log.